# How do I set up two monitors on two very different graphics cards?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ati, graphics, multiple-monitors

I have two video cards, one running each of two identical monitors. My main card is an Nvidia GeForce 750 Ti, and the secondary is a Radeon HD5500. When I boot from live USB, the monitor attached to the HD5500 displays the desktop, and the other displays a gray screen with a flashing cursor (but doesn't do anything else). After installing, the desktop shows up on the GeForce, and the Radeon monitor is blank.

I followed [this guide](http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/) to attempt to install proprietary Nvidia drivers, but it didn't work. So I tried downloading the package straight from Nvidia. I think that worked, but I'm not sure (I'm completely new to this). I then tried to select a different driver for the Radeon from the list on the Additional Drivers settings tab. Now when I boot Ubuntu, the Radeon monitor gets no signal, and the GeForce monitor displays black.

What did I do wrong, and how do I fix it?

Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot with Windows 8.1 U1

Comment: I think Xorg is incapable to span a desktop across multiple graphics adapters.

Comment: Is there any way around it using 3rd party software, proprietary drivers, etc? Seems like a strange limitation of something as open as Linux.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no software that can do this on Linux at the moment. “Open” means, that a solution is possible, not that a solution exists. It looks like you'll have to write drivers and modify the other involved subsystems yourself (or find somebody who does it for you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong.  What you're trying to do is "impossible".  Both graphics cards have their own discrete memory and you need a shared frame buffer between the two to make this work...

The [BumbleBee project](http://bumblebee-project.org/) is doing this for Intel and NVidia cards, but they don't support AMD/ATI cards, so unless you start programming this yourself for AMD, it's "impossible"... (for a certain definition of impossible.  Look up Charles De Gaulle)

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news...

Comment: That's unfortunate. So it's impossible to spread a desktop across multiple video cards, unless they are both Nvidia? But I can still do multiple monitors on a single card, right?

Comment: I know that with NVidia, it *is* possible, and with Bumblebee it is possible to combine Intel and NVidia.  I also know that with NVidia *and* ATI it's *not* possible...